# How to solve An error occurred while processing your request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have developed project using ASP.Net Core 3.1 and deployed into another computer in IIS Server, after run the project an error displayed.

```
Error.

An error occurred while processing your request.

Request ID: |211a0ec3-44255ebd8e81a907.

Development Mode

Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.
```

Here is my launchSettings.json

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54417",
      "sslPort": 44371
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },

     "EasyBooks": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
      }
    }
  }
```

My Project Properties under Debug under Environment variable is

```
Name:  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT 
Value:  Development
```

The community help to solve this error, please

Comment: FYI .NET Core 3.1 is no longer supported. You should use at least version 6.

Comment: Does your project running in local environment accordingly? While publishing on another machine what configuration did you had there?

Comment: I am new in using ASP.Net Core, this is my first app and faced this big challenge, so please bear with me and assist me to solve this error about ASPNETCORE_ENVIROMRNT VARIABLE. I used Martin Costello suggestion and work using online server but my problem want use iis server locally to host my first app in another computer. I just only installed iis server using turn windows features on or off button and ASP.Net Core Hosting bundle 3.1 in the machine used for hosting my app.

Answer (score 1):

> I have developed project using ASP.Net Core 3.1 and deployed into
> another computer in IIS Server, after run the project an error
> displayed.

Actually, this absolutely common in asp.net core application life cycle because according to the error it saying while you are trying to access `public IActionResult Error()` action method in publish mode for getting error details because its not recommended. You can see below:

[image]

In other words,  its not expected to expose error details in production mode and this why you are getting this specific error. If you navigate to `Error.cshtml` page within shared folder you would have seen that page which looks as following:

[image]

In addition to this, if you move to program.cs file you would have seen following code snippet:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

You always can configure above setting based on your environment.

On top of that, in `launchSettings.json` file you also can introduce your additional environment information, for instance, Production, Staging environment you can attach. You can [check here how to do that.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

**Note:** If you would like to know [more details you can check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#developer-exception-page-1)

Comment: Thanks Community for the effort. Error was gone after follow `Martin Costello` suggestion migrated to version 6 and make my database public, sysadmin and db_owner.

Comment: Thanks for your response and glad to know that your issue has been resolved.